# Why isn't string.split able to read my file in the following format?

Tags: java

In a text file I have the following:

```
${"a":"b"
}
${"a":"b"
}
${"a":"b"
}
${"a":"b"
}
```

Why am I unable to split the string into array of tokens using the following?

```
String [] tokens = readFile().split("$");
```

Here readFile() returns the entire string above read from a text file which works fine. I want the token array to return the individual {"a":"b"} as four elements of the array.

Answer (score 5):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expression as its argument. `$` is a the meta-character used to match the end of an input String. It needs to be escaped

```
String [] tokens = readFile().split("\\$");
```

otherwise the split will occur on the last character of the input.

Read [Special Characters section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Comment: very well. just what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Split accepts regex, not a plain String. $ is a regex expression.